# Получить queryset

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть представление на основе ListView. Оно работает и выводит список. Как получить другой queryset в зависимости от выбора пользователя? Например, пользователь выбирает способ сортировки и нажимает кнопку применить. Мне казалось, что если в методе post сделать так, то должно работать, но почему-то не работает.

```
self.queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-created')
```

Шаблон такой

```
<form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
         {% for f in form %}
         <div>{{ f }}</div>
         <div>{{ f.errors }}</div>
         {% endfor %}
         <div><button>Сортировать</button></div>
         {% for t in themes %}
         <li><p{{ t }}</p></li>
         {% endfor %}      
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class SortThenesForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SortThema.objects.all())
```

models.py

```
class SortThema(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
 class Forum(DataMixin, ListView):
        queryset = Thema.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        template_name = 'app_forum/forum.html'
        context_object_name = 'themes'

        def post(self, request):
            form = SortThenesForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.cleaned_data.get('choice').title == 'a':
                    self.queryset=Thema.objects.all().order_by('created')
                if form.cleaned_data.get('choice').title == 'b':
                    self.queryset=Thema.objects.all().order_by('upd')
            return redirect('forum')
```

Профессионалы, ау?)) Вроде, ведь тривиальная задача для вас должна быть. Представление выводит список тем. Чтобы их отсортировать создаю поле select с кнопкой для post запроса. Из списка выбираю пункт и нажимаю кнопку, но результат не меняется и в select возвращается старое значение. Функцией print проверял, что выводят значения - все правильно, что ожидаю, то и получается.
Предполагаю, что нужно прописать конструктор вот здесь

```
class SortThenesForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SortThema.objects.all())
```

и как-то передать ему выбранное значение из метода post, но, пока, не пойму как

Comment: Зачем вам post для сортировки?

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте уж лучше в `GET`, при F5 не будет хотя бы всплывать надоедливое окно.

Для сортировки переопределите метод `get_queryset` или `get_ordering`, берите значение из `self.request` и сортируйте, фильтруйте, делайте что хотите

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    order_by =  self.request.GET.get('sort')
    if order_by:
        qs = qs.order_by(order_by)
    return qs
```

```
def get_ordering(self):
    ordering = super().get_ordering()
    order_by =  self.request.GET.get('sort') or ''  # -is_active,created_at,id
    if order_by:
        ordering = order_by.split(',')
    return ordering
```

Выбирайте любой вариант

---

PS: В выходные люди обычно отдыхают

Comment: Понял, спасибо.